# Making changes to a config file via bash script

Tags: bash

All I want to do is change `Expiration_Date` field.

```
Name,Licence_Code,Expiration_Date,Renewal_Price,ID.No
Ruben,B,**2018-10-08**,R100,1111111111111
Gunther,C1,**2024-04-09**,R200,2222222222222
Tian,C,2019-12-11,R300,123
```

In my script there is a variable called `NEW_DATE` and I want to update the value of `Expiration_Date` with the value of `NEW_DATE`

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Please show what you have attempted and the issues you faced!!

Comment: `sed "s/^([^,]*,[^,]*,)[^,]*/\1$NEW_DATE/"` : capture the line from the start up to the field you wish to replace, representing fields and their separator ; put what doesn't change into a capturing group, replace by the capturing group and the updated data

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you intend :

```
awk -F',' -v new_value="$NEW_VALUE" 'BEGIN{ OFS=","}{if(NR != 1) { $3 = new_value }; print $0}' input.txt
```

Assuming *input.txt* is your file.

Regards!

Comment: shorter: `awk -v new_value="$NEW_VALUE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{$3=new_value}1' input.txt`